# AngularJs UI typeahead match exact

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to do a autocomplete with typeahead that match exact characters like t will match but not T.
But I cannot get it to work as I want.

Have tried to find a solution in google and stackoverflow like:
[AngularJs UI typeahead match on leading characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429967/angularjs-ui-typeahead-match-on-leading-characters)
[AngularJS Filter Exact Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480526/angularjs-filter-exact-match)

This is how my example code looks like:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mXthLrqNqpCyRYmj2qmT?p=preview

Thanks for helping.

Best Regards,
Johnny

Comment: Be more specificly. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: i guess he has misspelled 'not' with 'now' in first line

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for this [SEE HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/qZ3QNDPM00KOLj6WfBVy?p=preview)

actually you were comparing by lower case hence it fetched you result in case of 't' and 'T' both

```
 $scope.startsWith = function(state, viewValue) {
          return state.substr(0, viewValue.length) == viewValue;
        }
```

fetching records for T but not for t

Comment: I yes I am looking for something like that, but in that example they are using a simple array. I have a array of objects.

Comment: can you now see my plunker once more i have update it

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I think that I found what was wrong with my code. I have tried this before I ask for help "return state.substr(0, viewValue.length) == viewValue;" with filter|$viewValue:startsWith. In my solution I am using angularjs version 1.0.7 with bootstrap 0.6.0.

It seems that they don't play with each other so well. When I changed to angularjs version 1.1.5, everything works fine then.

You can test your plunk with a stable release like 1.0.8 and you will see what's happen.