# Typeahead with results starting with query ranked higher

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the AngulaJS `typeahead` directive like follows:

```
typeahead="elements.name for elements in someObject.elements | filter:{name:$viewValue} | orderBy:'name'
```

With the `$viewValue` being `'foo'` the output looks like this and in the exact order:

a **foo** goes first
after the **foo** goes a bar
bar comes before **foo**
**foo** comes after bar
**foo**bar is awesome

I'd like to have results starting with query being ranked higher, like this:

**foo** comes after bar
**foo**bar is awesome
a **foo** goes first
after the **foo** goes a bar
bar comes before **foo**

But I don't see any way to do this cleanly.

What I also tried was this:

```
$scope.startsWith = function (state, viewValue) {
   return state.substr(0, viewValue.length).toLowerCase() === viewValue.toLowerCase();
};
```

...using it like follows:

```
typeahead="elements.name for elements in someObject.elements | filter:{name:$viewValue}:startsWith | orderBy:'name'
```

The result was this:

**foo** comes after bar
**foo**bar is awesome

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Ben's approach which may be right in most cases, but for me it din't work because I have recursive ng-includes and cannot make use of ng-model.

Here is how I solved my problem (it's a little of a hack, I admit, but I'd call it *a clean hack*):

I misuse the following filter purposely, in order to save viewValue and the property on which the filter is applied as `queryObj` in my `typeaheadService` before ordering. I also use it to filter on a property of choice.

```
app.filter('typeaheadFilter', ['typeaheadService', function (typeaheadService) {
    return function (input, queryObj) {
        var key = Object.keys(queryObj)[0],
            query = queryObj[key];

        typeaheadService.setQueryObject(queryObj); // called once, when the viewValue changes

        if (!query) {
            return input;
        }
        var result = [];

        angular.forEach(input, function (object) {
            if (object[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                result.push(object);
            }
        });
        return result;
    };
}]);
```

And here is how the `typeaheadService` looks like (this service is used to set and get the query object for all typeaheads):

```
app.factory('typeaheadService', [
    function () {
        var typeaheadQueryObj;
        return {
            getQueryObject: function () {
                return typeaheadQueryObj;
            },
            setQueryObject: function (queryObj) {
                typeaheadQueryObj = queryObj;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

In my `MainController` I add my `smartOrder` function to the `$scope`:

```
$scope.smartOrder = function (obj) {
    var queryObj = typeaheadService.getQueryObject(),
        key = Object.keys(queryObj)[0],
        query = queryObj[key];
    if (obj[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
        return ('a' + obj[key]);
    }
    return ('b' + obj[key]);
};
```

Finally, my `typeahead`:

```
typeahead="element.name for element in elements | typeaheadFilter:{name:$viewValue} | orderBy:smartOrder | limitTo:dropdownMenuLimit"
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. But very much code. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change the orderBy, not the filter. Maybe doing a function instead of a property on the orderBy would achieve the desired effect.

Possibly something like

```
$scope.typeAheadModel = '';
$scope.orderByPriority = function (element) {
    return element.name.indexOf($scope.typeAheadModel);
}
```

And in your HTML add an `ng-model` on your input

```
ng-model="typeAheadModel" typeahead="element.name for element in someObject.elements | filter:{name:$viewValue} | orderBy:orderByPriority
```

**edit**

Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DodNL4xG6dp17u5qzNWf) of it, for some reason it doesn't do it properly when you type in just "f", but once you type in "fo" it orders it correctly. Not sure why.

Comment: Problem is, that the function `orderByPriority` doesn't receive the `viewValue` as an argument. So unfortunately this doesn't work. Any idea how to access the `viewValue` in a different way?

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks! I tried your approach, but for me it din't work because I have recursive ng-includes and cannot make use of ng-model. I've found a solution which works well for me (see my own answer). Anyway I'd like to know whether your approach, which seems to be right in a common scenario, works or not. Can you make plunker maybe?

Comment: Done. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: +1 for the prove of concept, though it's strange that just 'f' doesn't order the results correctly.

Comment: You can also do `orderBy:orderByPriority($viewValue)` and let orderByPriority return a function that does the scoring.

Answer (score 0):

Bens Approach is not bad, it was useful to me,  but it has a problem if your list contains uppercases.

so you have to transform the two endpoints:

```
$scope.typeAheadModel = '';

$scope.orderByPriority = function (element) {
    var lower_model = $scope.typeAheadModel.toLowerCase();
    var lower_name = element.name.toLowerCase();

    return lower_name.indexOf(lower_model);
}
```