# Typeahead each time user writes a certain word

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm using the ui-bootstrap typeahead for when a user types to show all the variables available for him to write which are proprieties from an object which is loaded Ex: item.cost+item.quantity.

My question is I want the suggestions only to appear each time user types "item.", I've notice the typeahead only works for one word and at the beginning.

html

```
<div class="modal-body">
          Add expression:
            <textarea style="width: 568px;" ng-model="item.formula"
                      uib-typeahead="state for state in states " 
                     typeahead-show-hint="true"
                     typeahead-on-select="item"
                      ng-change="eval(item.formula)">
            </textarea>
            <p><b>Result:</b> <br>
            <div style="width: 100%">{{ans}}
            </div>
            </p>
            </div>
```

controller

```
 ctrl.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.imageShowModal = function (item) { //loads the object items
    $scope.item = item;
    $scope.states =Object.keys(item); //get the JSON keys from item object like cost,price,quantity,workflow...
};

$scope.eval = function (v) {
    try {
        $scope.ans = $scope.$eval(v);
    } catch (e) {
    }
};
```

Comment: I would suggest writing your own directive where on keyDown event you could check if the pressed key was spacebar and then grab the last word from input field

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom filter in your `uib-typeahead` expression, ex: `uib-typeahead="state for state in states | myCustomFilter:$viewValue"`

A custom filter in your case might look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('myCustomFilter', function() {
    return function(list, term) {
      if (term.indexOf('item.') === -1)
        return [];

      var filteredList = [];
      angular.forEach(list, function(value) {
        if (value.indexOf(term) !== -1)
          filteredList.push(value);
      });

      return filteredList;
    }
  });
```

See also: [AngularJs UI typeahead match on leading characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429967/angularjs-ui-typeahead-match-on-leading-characters)

Comment: what do you mean by list and filteredList?

Comment: Your variable $scope.states is an array (or list) of keys. That is what is being filtered.

Comment: it says Unknown provider: listProvider <- list <- myCustomFilterFilter

Comment: Another this you have list at begin but you dont call him anywhere. And doesnt push anything to the filteredList.
Ive made a change i will create my list manually including the "item." because some key that i dont want to include. Another thing is if he writes again another variable to activate the typeahead. it only works at the begin i will try to make a plunk

Comment: Good catch, my forEach call was missing the first parameter. Doing this from memory on my mobile. I've updated my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101683/discussion-between-changez-and-shaun-scovil).