# Match results by beginning of words with uib-typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

Is it possible, with uib-typeahead, to match results as long as what is being typed matches *any* word in a source array's item? For the location example used in the documentation, I'd like to be able to type `ne yo` and see `New York` as one of the typeahead suggestions, because both words i entered match with words in `New York`.

If not possible, is there a similar alternative which can accomplish this

Comment: I think you need a custom filter to implement this logic. Possible applicable answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429967/angularjs-ui-typeahead-match-on-leading-characters